# Safe to delete innodb_status.* files?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Looking at the `/var/lib/mysql` folder on my Ubuntu 13.10 server I'm seeing a lot of files named `innodb_status.*`.

Running `ls -la` these files seem to have no size to them, but I don't want to delete them in case it's doing something important.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have **innodb-status-file** enabled in your settings?

Comment: I do not, so it must've been from an old setting I had turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MySQL pages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html) quoted below, I'd say "yes, you can (but stop the mysql-server first)".

> InnoDB sends diagnostic output to stderr or to files rather than to stdout or fixed-size memory buffers, to avoid potential buffer overflows. As a side effect, the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` is written to a status file in the MySQL data directory every fifteen seconds. The name of the file is `innodb_status.pid`, where pid is the server process ID. InnoDB removes the file for a normal shutdown. If abnormal shutdowns have occurred, instances of these status files may be present and must be removed manually. Before removing them, you might want to examine them to see whether they contain useful information about the cause of abnormal shutdowns. The `innodb_status.pid` file is created only if the configuration option `innodb-status-file=1` is set.

Comment: Every 15 seconds!? Woah. Thanks, I'll definitely be turning that option off.

Comment: I've just checked my config file and cann't see `innodb_status_file=1` anywhere. Perhaps this is an old setting I had?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'll say those files might appear if the mysql crashes or if you are having innodb monitoring? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-monitors.html